# How can I convert this Python mutable function into immutable?

Tags: python, list, immutability

I have a mutable Fibonacci function that mutates a list in order to return that list as a fib sequence. I want to do the same thing... but the list (or tuple in this case) should not be able to change. The return still has to send the whole list, how can I implement this, without using recursion.

Ex) if x = 6... list should return {1,1,2,3,5,8}

I'm running in python 3.5

Here is my code:

```
def mutableFib(x):
result = []
for y in range(0,x):
    if y < 2:
        result.append(1)
    else:
        last = result[y - 1]
        previous = result[y - 2]
        result.append(last + previous) //result is being changed
return result
```

Comment: Think about the difference between changing a list and making a new tuple then refactor as needed.  Please format your code.

Comment: You can also add two tuples together

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new list for every new element.

```
def fibonacci(x):
    list_of_fibonaccis = []
    for y in range(0,x):
        if y < 2:
            temp_fibonacci = [1] * (y + 1)
        else:
            last = list_of_fibonaccis[y-1][-1]
            previous = list_of_fibonaccis[y-1][-2]
            temp_fibonacci = list_of_fibonaccis[y-1] + [last + previous]
        list_of_fibonaccis.append(temp_fibonacci)
    return list_of_fibonaccis[-1]
```

Comment: that doesn't change the fact that result is still being modified. I need a more functional programming approach... and I can't figure out how to do that

Comment: I see what you mean, and have updated my answer. However, I don't see why you would want to do this, or what you mean by 'functional'....

Comment: in this... both temp_fibonacci and list_of_fibonaccis is constantly changing within a for loop. the goal is to avoid doing that.

Comment: temp_fibonacci is simply a reference to the actual list, which isn't being changed. It is the reference to the newest fibonacci sequence that is changed. Once the fibonacci sequences are made, they are stored in list_of_fibonaccis, not being further changed.

Comment: Besides, it is impossible to have a not changing list, as the computer can only do one thing at a time (unless you are multiprocessing). That means that the elements of any list will have to be put in place one after another, not simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean by "a functional approach that doesn't use recursion," it seems like the input parameter should be a list of the first n Fibonacci numbers and the output should be a list of the first n+1 Fibonacci numbers.  If this is correct, then you could use

```
def fibonacci(fib):
    if not fib: return [1]
    if len(fib) == 1: return [1,1]
    return fib + [fib[-1]+fib[-2]]
```